# Using keys.join() on a attributes and appending data

Tags: chef-infra

I have two set's of attributes i need to combine in Chef

```
Set 1
cert1.sec1.offdtr.dev
cert2.sec1.offdtr.dev

Set 2
cert3.sec2.ondrt.dev,
cert4.sec2.ondrt.dev
```

I can use keys.join(',') on each data set to concat them together.

```
<% node['code']['block'][sec1].keys.join(','),node['code']['block'][sec2].keys.join(',') %>
```

But i need a second action ; append */ to each value. Output should be something like :

```
*/cert1.sec1.offdtr.dev,*/cert2.sec1.offdtr.dev,*/cert3.sec2.ondrt.dev,*/cert4.sec1.ondrt.dev
```

How can i do this in a chef template?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in Chef template, we need to use `<%=` (note the `=` sign) to get the value of attributes/variables rendered. Along with this, we can use `,*/` to join the keys.

So if you put something like below in a template (`.erb`) file:

```
*/<%= node['code']['block']['sec1'].keys.join(',*/') %>,*/<%= node['code']['block']['sec2'].keys.join(',*/') %>
```

It will produce the expected result when rendered:

```
*/cert1.sec1.offdtr.dev,*/cert2.sec1.offdtr.dev,*/cert3.sec2.ondrt.dev,*/cert4.sec2.ondrt.dev
```

---

In a recipe we use `#{..}` for interpolation of variables. For e.g. when the `mycerts` variable defined below is used elsewhere, it will result in exactly the same result.

```
mycerts = "*/#{node['cookbook1']['sec1'].keys.join(',*/')},*/#{node['cookbook1']['sec2'].keys.join(',*/')}
```

Comment: This indeed works, thanks. And how would i do it in a chef recipe..?

Comment: Once it is set in a recipe, how/where do you want to use it?